# Please help me isolate this variable

Tags: functions

I need to isolate 'B' in the following equation:
$$
E\left( \left({A-B\over C}\right)^2 -D^2 \right) = B(1-B)
$$
Can anyone help? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If you expand everything, you get a quadratic polynomial in $B$. What do you know about quadratic polynomials to help you solve for $B$?

Comment: Absolutely nothing I'm afraid... this is all new to me